# How do you refer to the feasible set of solutions to a mixed-integer program?

Tags: convex-polytopes, integer-programming

I frequently want to refer to the feasible set of solutions to a mixed integer programming instance. Is there a name for a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n\times\{0,1\}^m$ of the form $\{(x,a)| Ax + Ba\leq b\}$, where $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $a\in\{0,1\}^m$?

Comment: the "feasible region" has been used as an alternative to "feasible set"

Comment: Sure, but I'm hoping for maybe something like "Mixed-integer polytope" used in some literature somewhere. My complaint is essentially that I just want a short, concise handle to refer to the feasible region of a MIP